# How to search a specific tag from underlying ASP

Tags: javascript

The frame has the following structure

```
Frames
  |- about:blamk
  file1.asp
  |-Frames (dir)
     | a.html
```

From file1.asp (which contains the below code)

```
<html lang="en">
<head>

< ...snipped code ... >

<iframe id="upFrame" name="upFrame" onload="attachmentIFrameOnLoad(this);" src="/ics/blank.html" height="0" width="0" style="display:none"></iframe>


<table id="winTab__title" width='100%' class='winTab title'><tr><td class=winHeader><span id=title><a target="_blank" href="/link/desk/8745/31036/Ticket/123456">***Information 8475-123456: I want to get this stuff***</a></span></td></tr></table><table id=winTab__columns width='100%' class='winTab ' style='' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td class='winTabOpen'>&nbsp;</td><td class='winTabContent'><table width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr>
 <td  class='winButtonPress2' nowrap   data-hoverclass="winButtonPressActive2" data-unhoverclass="winButtonPress2" onMouseUp="javascript:return false;" > 
<img src='/ics/inc/css/parature/images/icons/iTicket.png' alt='My Info' border='0' class='HEIGHT:16px; WIDTH:16px;' align='absmiddle' >&nbsp;My Info</td>
```

How can I extract

```
***Information 8475-123456: I want to get this stuff***
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Are you just trying to get the innerHTML from that `<a>` tag? Is the `title` id always going to be there? `document.getElementById('title').children[0].innerHTML;`

Comment: Yes. I am trying to get the innerHTML from the <a> tag.

Comment: Is the page structure subject to change? Do you need to do this one time, or on demand?

Comment: The page structure will remain the same. Except the information in that table is going to change for eg: Information 8978-127658 Another Message.  This script is in an iFrame. So I need to get this on demand. The script that is being executed will be from a browser plugin. The plugin has to read the iFrame source and extract the information out.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `id` attribute to the `<a>` tag that contains your string.

Then you can extract its content using [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById):

```
<a id='your-id' ...>***Information 8475-123456: I want to get this stuff***</a>
```

---

```
var content = document.getElementById('your-id').innerHTML;
```

If you can't add any attributes to the HTML elements, work with the existing ones as pointed out in the comments:

```
var content = document.getElementById('title').children[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: unfortunately I can not add anything. I have to extract that information from an existing page. Given the above code from the existing page is there a way I can extract that string?

Comment: Hi TimoSta,

document.getElementById('title').children[0].innerHTML works when I tested with the frame in a new tab. However in the existing window with other frames, I get null. Any idea how to make the frame current and get the value?

Many Thanks,
Chenulu